# How to apply function on each row in a group after groupby in pyspark?

Tags: user-defined-functions, pyspark

I have data like this:

- userID sessionID time
- "" xxx 2019-06-01
- "" xxx 2019-06-02
- user1 xxx 2019-06-03
- "" yyy 2019-06-04
- user2 yyy 2019-06-05
- "" yyy 2019-06-06
- user3 yyy 2019-06-07

What I want is:

- userID sessionID time
- user1 xxx 2019-06-01
- user1 xxx 2019-06-02
- user1 xxx 2019-06-03
- user2 yyy 2019-06-04
- user2 yyy 2019-06-05
- user3 yyy 2019-06-06
- user3 yyy 2019-06-07

Can I group by on seesionID and apply a UDF on each group and get userID of each row in each session.

update:
I solved it by replacing empty string with null then:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
import sys
# define the window
window = Window.partitionBy('jsession')\
               .orderBy('request_time')\
               .rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize)

# define the forward-filled column
filled_column = first(df['userid'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
# do the fill
df = df.withColumn('filled_userid', filled_column)
```

Comment: Need more details, how row1 and row2  will have userID - user1 ... ans so on

Comment: thanks, I have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

replace empty string "" with null then:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
import sys
# define the window
window = Window.partitionBy('jsession')\
               .orderBy('request_time')\
               .rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize)

# define the forward-filled column
filled_column = first(df['userid'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
# do the fill
df = df.withColumn('filled_userid', filled_column)
```